# Load external URL html on same page, needs to have navigation page1,2,3..., Cannot use iframes, tried using DIV'S but messes up external source's CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, iframe

first time posting, i've searched, here's what I want to do, old implementation used iframe (had one iframe for the navigation, another for the URL) but no longer works with Chrome, cannot enable iframe's.  The links are like this:

Here's what I've tried thanks to searching on the forum:

```js
$(function(){
          var $cur = $('#group .current');
          var $items = $('#group .item');
          
          function hideButtons() {
            $cur = $('#group .current');
            var index = $cur.index();
            if(index > 0) {
              $('#prev').show();
            } else {
              $('#prev').hide();
            }
            
            if(index < $items.length - 1) {
              $('#next').show();
            } else {
              $('#next').hide();
            }
            
            
          }
          
          hideButtons();
          
          $('#next').click(function(){
            $cur.next().addClass('current');
            $cur.removeClass('current');
            hideButtons();
          });
          $('#prev').click(function(){
            $cur.prev().addClass('current');
            $cur.removeClass('current');
            hideButtons();
          });
        });
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;


}
.center {
  width: 800px;
 height: 90%;

}



.item {
  display: none;
  }

.item.current {
  display: block;
  }
.rptButton
{
  width: 80px;

}
.navButton
{
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/javax.faces.resource/jquery-1.7.2.min.js.xhtml?ln=javascripts"></script>


<style type="text/css"> 


</style> 

</head>
<title></title>
<body >
      <div style="text-align: center">
<button id="next" class="navButton">next</button>
<button style="display:none" id="prev" class="navButton">previous</button>
  </div>


       <div class="container" >
        <div class="center" id="previewFrame"  title="Preview Frame">
        <div id="group" >
              <!-- display page 1 no matter what-->
        <div id="divIDNo1" class="current item">

                    <c:url value="<%=openURL%>" var="myURLCustom">
                        <c:param name="page" value="1" />
                    </c:url>
                    <c:import url="${myURLCustom}" />
                </div>
        <!-- display page 2 and so on-->
        
      <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "2" end = "<%=numOfPages%>" varStatus="theCount">
        <div id="divIDNo${theCount.index}" class="item" >
    <c:import url="<%=openURL%>"> 
        <c:param name="page" value="${i}"/></c:import>
        </div>
      </c:forEach>
      </div>
</div>
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

This works but after page 1, the CSS of the source page messed up, fonts get larger, others smaller, lines disappear.

I have also tried loading the external pages, say 10 pages, with page breaks but the preview windows clumps the pages together even though the print option displays them correctly.

I've tried looking at MutationObserver but still a newbie at coding and don't know how to implement this.

The URL's are like this:

http://localhost:8080/viewDoc?entry=abc?page=1, then ?page=2, ?page=3,....

They need to load in the popup window, and then navigation (next, previous, first, last) to go to the next URL but popup window must stay open and only the content must change (page 1, 2, 3....)

Comment: Iframes have there own `window` and `document` which are completely isolated from parent page window which means they can use completely different css styles and their own javascript with no conflicts in parent window. Without completely styling their components to be compatible in the parent document what you are up against is not trivial

Comment: Note that chrome still supports `<iframe>`s so perhaps identifying the specific error encountered would help. If they were very old `<frameset>` and `<frame>` that is a different story as that is very obsolete and dates back to early internet days

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway to accomplish without using iframes?  I tried tried document.open and document.location but that’s good to open one url but don’t know how to navigate using document.open on the same pop up page, to the next page url.

Comment: I would also add the url I’m trying to load is a simple static html page that has a company header, some tables , titles, some content, and a footer.  

I wonder if I can simply some how grab the url source hrml, put into a string on my pop up page, and render that into a div or some other element.

Comment: Yes but I you seem to be doing that somewhat already which is generating the visual style issues

Comment: Thanks Charlie, you’re right. Divs are not working for me.      

I will also add I don’t mind the pop up page refreshing.  But the pop up must have navigation.     

I’m okay with all the urls ( about 25 pages) being loaded on one pop up page but having problems then with the page breaks on the pop up page.  Page break before and after on the DIV work fine for if you want to hit Cntrl+P but the pop up page just overlaps.       

I put like 10-20  <br> But the pages loaded may have different lengths so this doesn’t work.